# Improve the Swig-tcl wrapping of a make function

Tags: c++, tcl, swig

When wrapping a constructor like:

```
struct A {
  A(){}
  void hello() {std::cout << "hello\n";}
};
```

Swig-tcl is amazing! Indeed in tcl I can just do:

```
A a
a hello
```

However there are cases where the creation of the object `a` is not straightforward (i.e. I may just want to return a reference to another object on the heap) and has to go through a make function like:

```
A make(){ return A(); }
```

then the wrapping of Swig-tcl becomes quite a mess:

```
set a [make]
$a hello
```

I am wondering if there is a way to restore the initial clarity of the tcl script when using a make function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's particularly messy! It's just that the command in the second case has a name that you don't control, so you're keeping the name in a variable.

You can either rename the object command or make an alias to it:

```tcl
rename $a a
```

```tcl
interp alias {} a {} $a
```

After using either of those techniques, you'll have a command called `a` which you can invoke methods on. ***However,*** in both cases, if you're passing the object as an argument to another SWIGged function or method, you need the *original* name. Because of that, I'd personally advise just using the version with the name in a variable.

<sup>You should check that the version with `rename` works; it's possible — though unlikely — that it might not…</sup>